# D3 chart works works perfectly on jsfiddle but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

So I'm trying to get this jsfiddle working:

http://jsfiddle.net/davetaz/Xc8nT/

It works perfectly on there.

However, when I go to my machine and use the code(just to see if it works before making my own changes) it doesn't work, just get the grey div. There are no errors in the console.

The order of my code is as follows:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

then the div

```
  <div id="chart"></div>
```

then the script.

I've tried wrapping in `$( document ).ready`, tried it in an external file with that as well. Nothing seems to work. I'm at wits end trying to figure this out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your HTML page properly formatted? The following works fine for me:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style>
#chart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #bbb;
  font-size: 10px;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grandparent text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
}

rect.parent,
.grandparent rect {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.grandparent rect {
  fill: #fff;
}

.children rect.parent,
.grandparent rect {
  cursor: pointer;
}

rect.parent {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.children:hover rect.child,
.grandparent:hover rect {
  fill: #aaa;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
var data = {
    "name": "projects",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Department of Agriculture",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Annual Agency Operations.",
                    "value": 15.297
                },
                {
                    "name": "Program Areas will migrate their data over to the agencys virtual servers and shut down their current server.",
                    "value": 0.179
                },
                {
                    "name": "Programs Areas will replace 1/3 of their computers which have an expired warranty.",
                    "value": 1.46
                },
                {
                    "name": "Production Support including Analysis, Software Fixes, System Software Upgrades, Help Desk.",
                    "value": 1.8205
                },
                {
                    "name": "Production Support including Analysis, Software Fixes, System Software Upgrades, Help Desk. (1)",
                    "value": 1.713
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Department of Commerce",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Parallel test components of new BP system.",
                    "value": 1.24
                },
                {
                    "name": "Initiate real-time parallel testing of integrated system for producing monthly GDP and personal income estimates.",
                    "value": 0.413
                },
                {
                    "name": "Produce timely, relevant, and accurate economic accounts data in an objective and cost-effective manner.",
                    "value": 9.696
                },
                {
                    "name": "Maintain the integrity of BEA Statistics by completing independent testing of security controls.",
                    "value": 0.59
                },
                {
                    "name": "Produce timely, relevant, and accurate economic accounts data in an objective and cost-effective manner. (1)",
                    "value": 9.76
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

// This example has been adapted from Mike Bostocks Zooming treemap example at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/. Many thanks to Mike for his excellent work in this area. 

var margin = {top: 30, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    width = 500,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
    transitioning;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([0, height]);

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d.children; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
    .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
    .round(false);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
    .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

var grandparent = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grandparent");

grandparent.append("rect")
    .attr("y", -margin.top)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", margin.top);

grandparent.append("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
    .attr("dy", ".75em");

initialize(data);
accumulate(data);
layout(data);
display(data);

function initialize(root) {
    root.x = root.y = 0;
    root.dx = width;
    root.dy = height;
    root.depth = 0;
}

// Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
// treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
function accumulate(d) {
    return d.children
        ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
        : d.value;
}

// Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
// uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
// This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
// object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
// the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
// of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
// coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
function layout(d) {
   if (d.children) {
      treemap.nodes({children: d.children});
      d.children.forEach(function(c) {
        c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
        c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
        c.dx *= d.dx;
        c.dy *= d.dy;
        c.parent = d;
        layout(c);
      });
   }
}

function display(d) {
    grandparent
        .datum(d.parent)
        .on("click", transition)
        .select("text")
        .text(name(d));

    var g1 = svg.insert("g", ".grandparent")
        .datum(d)
        .attr("class", "depth");

    var g = g1.selectAll("g")
        .data(d.children)
      .enter().append("g");

    g.filter(function(d) { return d.children; })
        .classed("children", true)
        .on("click", transition);

    g.selectAll(".child")
        .data(function(d) { return d.children || [d]; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "child")
        .call(rect);

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "parent")
        .call(rect)
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.value); });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .call(text);

    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
    var colors = {};
    g.filter(function(d) {
        var parent_depth = (d.parent).depth;
        var current_node = d;
        if (parent_depth != 0) {
            current_node = d.parent;
        }
        if (!current_node.color) {
            current_node.color = color(current_node.name);
        }
    $(this).find(".child").css("fill",current_node.color);
    });

    function transition(d) {
      if (transitioning || !d) return;
      transitioning = true;

      var g2 = display(d),
          t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
          t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

      // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
      x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
      y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

      // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
      svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

      // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
      svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) { return a.depth - b.depth; });

      // Fade-in entering text.
      g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

      // Transition to the new view.
      t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
      t2.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
      t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
      t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

      // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
      t1.remove().each("end", function() {
        svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
        transitioning = false;
      });
    }

    return g;
}

function text(text) {
    text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; });
}

function rect(rect) {
    rect.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); })
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; });
}

function name(d) {
    return d.parent
        ? name(d.parent) + "." + d.name
        : d.name;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok so I actually had the div within a bootstrap container and thats what seems to be giving it trouble for some reason. I just went through deleting divs until I finally came to that conclusion, so I'll accept yours for checking for me :)